# C valgrind memory leakage

Tags: c, memory, valgrind

Hi my Valgrind shows me memory error but I cant find it.

> ==18608== HEAP SUMMARY:
>
> ==18608==     in use at exit: 88 bytes in 1 blocks
>
> ==18608==   total heap usage: 4 allocs, 3 frees, 2,220 bytes allocated
>
> ==18608==
>
> ==18608== Searching for pointers to 1 not-freed blocks
>
> ==18608== Checked 53,708 bytes
>
> ==18608==
>
> ==18608== 88 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
>
> ==18608==    at 0x402D17C: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
>
> ==18608==    by 0x8
>   0485BF: pmalloc (in auf)
>
> ==18608==    by 0x8048680: main (in auf)
>
> ==18608==
>
> ==18608== LEAK SUMMARY:
>
> ==18608==    definitely lost: 88 bytes in 1 blocks
>
> ==18608==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
>
> ==18608==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
>
> ==18608==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
>
> ==18608==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
>
> ==18608==
>
> ==18608== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
>
> ==18608== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)

Comment: Could you please paste your code here instead of displaying it as an image?

Comment: return value of `pmalloc` must be saved. and using then `free`.

Comment: thanks for the answer but how do i save the returned value i dont understand

Answer (score 1):

You allocate two different `int *`s; you don't free the first resource but you free the second one without doing anything with it:

```
print_prim(pmalloc(n), laenge);
free(pmalloc(laenge));
```

To free the first resource properly, you would do something like this:

```
int *p = pmalloc(n);
print_prim(p, laenge);
free(p);
```